# Badge doesn't update reputation in real-time

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

My Ask Ubuntu badge is inserted on my personal blog. So, when I visit my blog or I write on it, I can also check my status updates. But today, I have observed that the updates are not not in real-time, if I may say so.

I mean that while on the Ask Ubuntu site, the reputation changes, my badge keeps showing the old reputation. Since is about something that I have observed only today, I can't say if it is something temporary or permanent. I suppose that tomorrow or in the following days, things will be remedied. But still, it is something odd and if should be solved.

I would like to know what should I do, if I can do something about this problem.

**Later edit**

Meanwhile, my badge was updated. It seems to me that it is a delay of several hours. But the main problem / question still remains. Why it does not update instantly?

Comment: Neither badges, nor flair, nor email updates come in real time. That would take too much server power.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you need to do is be patient.

Updates for a whole variety of statistics do not update in real time, including, but not limited to;

- tag reputation
- tag badges
- reputation badges
- others

These processes are actioned by scripts running at set intervals in the background. Certain actions (like receiving the mortarboard badge, amongst others) only run once a day, while others will run multiple times per day.

Be patient, you will get the badge(s) and your profile will update when the script next runs.